# Relative pronoun or elipsis ? : 'for those who the disease seeks to attack'

Tags: relative-pronouns

This sentence was spoken recently in the British House of Lords :

> It would be wrong of me to mislead the house by pretending that there was an easy way out of this epidemic for **those who the disease seeks to attack.**
>
> Lord Bethell - Quoted by [The Guardian on MSN News 23/04/20](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/news/coronavirus/older-people-could-face-extended-coronavirus-lockdown-lords-hears/ar-BB135DjM?li=BBoPWjQ&ocid=mailsignout)

Rather than be pedantic and say 'whom the disease seeks to attack' is it actually better to miss out the relative pronoun altogether and simply say :

> ... those the disease seeks to attack ?

Comment: If you have the verve (in New York and New Jersey, we use other words) to edit the Lord, yes, that's a good edit.

Comment: @YosefBaskin  Far be it from me to edit your comment :) but did you mean 'nerve' rather than 'verve' ?

Comment: The implication was chutzpah in the sense of balls. Nerve would serve, but verve should swerve the reader to pause and think, "What other word is the off word?" In the right sense, verve and chutzpah are good when you use them, sketchy when others do. Nerve is more of a negative.

Comment: @YosefBaskin So ... panache, maybe ?

Comment: On a curve – "... for those at risk from the disease."

Comment: If suggesting *one* correction for what Lord Bethell said would be pedantic, isn't suggesting another just as pedantic?

Comment: @RosieF My thought was for his Lordship to miss it out when he actually spoke. Then we would not have to correct him.